# ethers.js call to contract transaction fails

Tags: ethereum, ethers.js, hardhat

Newbie to ethereum development...

I am using the sample code to keep it as simple as possible.
Using ethers.js and HardHat running on my local network.
The read function works ie. const data = await contract.greet()
The writes do not.

This code does not work, it just silently fails:

```
  async function setGreeting() {
    if (!greeting) return
    if (typeof window.ethereum !== 'undefined') {
      try {
        await requestAccount()
        const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum)
        const signer = provider.getSigner()
        const contract = new ethers.Contract(
          greeterAddress,
          Greeter.abi,
          signer,
        )
        console.log('contract address = ' + contract.address) // this displays correctly
        const transaction = await contract.setGreeting(greeting)
        console.log('transaction = ' + transaction) // never displays
        await transaction.wait()
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
      }
    }
  }
```

No error is thrown.

This line seems to be causing the issue:

```
        const transaction = await contract.setGreeting(greeting)
```

All I see when testing is what seems to be an exception but nothing logged.
No transaction displays in HardHat.

What am I missing? Should an exception not be thrown?

Thanks!

Comment: Possibly early return because of the conditions on the first two lines of the function. Can you check the values of `greeting` and `typeof window.ethereum`?

Comment: Console logging shows there values as "hello v4" for the greeting and "Proxy {_events: {…}, _eventsCount: 1, _maxListeners: 100, _log: u, _state: {…}, …}" for window.ethereum. I know the code is being executed as I log the contract address but the logging for transaction never executes.

Comment: After resetting the account in Metamask (Settings->Advanced->Reset Account) the code works the first time I run it. The transaction is successful and the greeting is updated. If I run it again, it fails silently. If I reset again, it works.